# Is "I like those except apple" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, except

I was helping to explain the difference between "except for" and "except" and my friend made two example sentences. Those two sentences being:

> I like those except apple

and

> I like those except for apple

They sound unnatural to me, but I am unsure whether they are incorrect or not. Can someone please explain this sentence to me and if it is correct or not?

Comment: If someone said, "I like orange, apple, pineapple, grape, blueberry, cherry, and strawberry."  Someone could then say, "I like those [too] - except [for] apple."   (Square bracketed words are optional) But without context, the word *those* has no antecedent.

Comment: @Jim So it's correct if there is proper context? Ah, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct.  The second reads most naturally.  However both read rather unnaturally.

A more natural sentence would be:

> I like all of those except for apple.

But that is probably just personal preference.